# Java - input first name middle initial and last name?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a java program that takes the firstname mi last name input and outputs "FI MI lastname"

thank you.

this is for a friend and i've not programed in ...... 15 years.

Comment: Must this run on android? Should it be done through GUI or console? Why did not you program for 15 years?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on Google's AppInventor ;) http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/